# jquery this concat selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example given this HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>p0</p>
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
</div>
```

I don't understand how to write a concatenated jQuery `this` selector, that is something like this:

```
$("div").on("mouseover", function () {
    $(this + " p").css({
        color: "#009"
    });
});
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Like this: `$(this).find("p").css(...`

Comment: I think what you looking for is just `$('p', this)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To find elements within another, use a contextual selector. Try this:

```
$("p", this).css({ /* ... */ });
```

Or you can concatenate the `id` of the parent - although this is a little ugly IMO:

```
$("#" + this.id + " p").css({ /* ... */ });
```

Or you can use `find()` on the parent element:

```
$(this).find("p").css({ /* ... */ });
```

Any of the above will work for you, although the second example is pretty ugly and should be avoided. Always use the `this` reference directly where possible.

Answer (score 6):

The jQuery selector takes an optional second argument, called the "selector context". From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the `$()` function... Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so `$('span', this)` is equivalent to `$(this).find('span')`.

**ANSWER**: You want `$("p", this)` or, equivalently (but more verbosely), `$(this).find("p")` in place of your `$(this+" p")`. This will limit your selection to `<p>`s that are descendant elements of the element contained in `this`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `$('p', this)` which basically returns all `p` tag in `this` context.